# How Can I use Javascript to loop through an array and change and add extra HTML that outputs some text with those values?

Tags: javascript, html, json, loops, dom

For Example, I am using an API that returns an JSON array of values and I want to output them to the page.

[Here is the full code I am working with](https://pastebin.com/raw/pkzHnFx5) if anyone wants to try it out to see where I can get it to work.

I have created Some HTML for the layout of the values I want to output when a button is clicked like so:

```
<p class="txData"> 
    <p id="txHash">Transaction ID: </p><br>
    <p id="txTime">Time: </p><br>
    <p id="txToken">Token Symbol: </p><br>
    <p id="txTo">To: </p><br>
    <p id="txFrom">From: </p><br>
    <p id="txValue">Amount Transferred: </p><br>
    <p>***********************************</p><br>
</p>
```

I then assign variables for those elements which I want to append to:

```
        let txHash = document.querySelector('#txHash');
        let txTime = document.querySelector('#txTime');
        let txToken = document.querySelector('#txToken');
        let txTo = document.querySelector('#txTo');
        let txFrom = document.querySelector('#txFrom');
        let txValue = document.querySelector('#txValue');
```

And I append the retrieved values from the API by doing:
                    txHash.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', jsonFile.result[0].hash);

```
                txTime.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', jsonFile.result[0].timeStamp);

                txToken.insertAdjacentText('beforeend', jsonFile.result[0].tokenSymbol)

                txTo.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', jsonFile.result[0].to);

                txFrom.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', jsonFile.result[0].from);

                txValue.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', web3.utils.fromWei(jsonFile.result[0].value, 'ether'));
```

This works to output the values wanted for the first Transaction (index [0]).

How could I create a loop that would basically use the template HTML at the start but then output it for the next 5 elements in the array so that it would be the details for each new trasanction outputted in the same format, but without having to code it 5 times?

I'm new to HTML and Javascript so appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Why is it that you want to use JavaScript? Can't you use jQuery instead?

Comment: Basically what you are trying to make is a table, right?

Comment: Kind of a table in this case, but I'm trying to understand how I will be able to do it more generally for if I want to do it on a site or app where I can list a users transaction history within their profile.

Comment: Can you show a representative snippet of the JSON you're receiving (ideally with two records as a minimum) and what HTML you want to end up with?

Comment: @chŝdk That does not work as that would only append all of those values to the same element. like this: https://i.imgur.com/gNUvgg1.png

Comment: @DavidThomas This is  a link to the JSON I receive: https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=account&action=tokentx&contractaddress=0x86fa049857e0209aa7d9e616f7eb3b3b78ecfdb0&address=0x46f91f0025c303d66958fd84feec3605e9363067&page=1&offset=100&sort=asc&apikey=YourApiKeyToken 

The HTML I would like to end up with is basically: https://pastebin.com/raw/AYq4YJ5a

But for each index of the array, and where the value after the colon which I have in square brackets, are the actual values from the javascript taken from the JSON array. if that makes sense?

Comment: @Abinthaha I am not against using it, I just don't know how to. If you can recommend where to start (which jQuery functionality I should google), I may look into that. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnMurphy: You can start with `each` which will help you iterate through your data (just like forEach/for) and then you can use `append` which will help you to append your data to the DOM element. Let me know if you want further help;

Comment: @JohnMurphy I understand asking the question, but I think you could have solved this with some research. It’s a fairly basic problem. Next time try a google search or have a look at [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Comment: @ElliotSchep I did try those things first.

Comment: @JohnMurphy I'm proud of you. I didn't downvote your question, because it **is** a good question, but I do wonder if a little more time spent researching could have solved it.

Answer (score 2):

First piece of advice, if you don't already know it, you should avoid using static id's in your html template if you plan to use it for displaying a list, because id's must be unique in a single html page.

Second one, you should use a framework to help you displaying your data as a list. If you know famous ones such as Angular or React. You can also use jQuery as someone has advised you.

Here is a little example with VueJS which allows you to define components with html templates. Then, you can use them in a loop with the for directive (please note I'm not a VueJS expert and you may find better solutions) :

```
<body>
    <div id="app">
      <div v-for="json in jsonFile">
        <data-display v-bind:json="json"></data-display>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      
      var DataDisplay = {
        props: ['json'],
        template: '<div class="txData">\
                    <p>Transaction ID: {{json.hash}}</p>\
                    <p id="txTime">Time: {{json.timeStamp}}</p>\
                    <p id="txToken">Token Symbol: {{json.tokenSymbol}}</p>\
                    <p id="txTo">To: {{json.to}}</p>\
                    <p id="txFrom">From: {{json.from}}</p>\
                    <p id="txValue">Amount Transferred: {{json.value}}</p>\
                    <p>***********************************</p>\
                   </div>'
      };
      
      var vm = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
          jsonFile: [
            {
              hash: 'hash1',
              timeStamp: 'timestamp1',
              tokenSymbol: 'token1',
              to: 'to1',
              from: 'from1',
              value: 'value1'
            }, {
              hash: 'hash2',
              timeStamp: 'timestamp2',
              tokenSymbol: 'token2',
              to: 'to2',
              from: 'from2',
              value: 'value2'
            }
          ]
        }, 
        components: {
          'data-display': DataDisplay
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
```

Documentation used for the example :

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html
- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html